# ActiveRecord two way foreign key.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, foreign-keys, associations

I'm using some open gov data in MYSQL which I've imported into my rails App.

I've extended the database with some of my own tables, and use the rails provided column ids in my tables.

However, the tables of the original database are linked through a unique 'ndb' id.

I thought that by cross-referencing two `:foreign_key=>'ndb'` between the models I would get the tables linked properly, but through `:foreign_key`, it appears to be linking the id from one table to the ndb column of another.

My models look like this

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :weights, :foreign_key=>'ndb'
has_many :food_names
end

class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :food, :foreign_key=>'ndb'
```

Is there a way to specify that the 'ndb' column is the link between the food and weights table, and not the food_id to ndb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done as a possibly temporary solution, is to used the `:finder_sql` to link the tables together.

My Food model now has:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weights, :finder_sql =>'Select weights.* FROM weights LEFT JOIN foods ON foods.ndb=weights.ndb WHERE foods.id=#{id}'
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution or not, but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `set_primary_key 'ndb'` in your AR classes?

[set_primary_key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D) docs.

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but I still need to use the _id fields in other queries as not everything is linked through the that 'ndb' field, which is what I meant by 'extended the database to use some of my own tables', so 70% of the time, I'm using the standard rails ids, but then sometimes I need to link 'ndb to ndb'

Comment: Well, using set_primary_key for those tables that need it will be a start, allowing things like find() to work. It'll also set defaults for associations.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear. For something like the food table, I use the id field 70 % of the time (sticking with rails standards) the other 30% of the time, I need to link that foods table to another table like weights through the ndb field. Setting the set_primary_key on the model breaks 70% of those relationships. unless I'm missing something else. Once I set 'ndb' as the primary key, I can't seem to connect two tables with id to food_id